# Type Object is not able to cast into Some Class C#

Tags: c#, casting

Below is a class with property name "d" and type is object

```
public class JsonRow
    {
        public bool check { get; set; }
        public string col0 { get; set; }
        public string col1 { get; set; }
        public string col2 { get; set; }
        public object d { get; set; }
        public string sender { get; set; }
    }
//Any generic class
public class MyClass {
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}

List<JsonRow> dataRows { get; set; }
dataRows = new List<JsonRow>();
dataRows.Add(new JsonRow() { 
    col0 = "A", 
    col1 = "B", 
    d = new MyClass() { 
        Property1="SomeValue", 
        Property2="XYZ" } 
});
```

Now, I am returning JsonResult as

```
return Json(dataRows , JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
```

Till here everthing is fine,

Issue: when I am posting back this Json object from Angular to Controller then property "d" is not able to cast into MyClass

```
var col0 = item.col0 //No error here and getting value
var mycls = (MyClass) item.d; //Error is coming
```

Comment: So you have an error, but you didn't think it was relevant to post _what_ the error was?  Was it an `InvalidCastException` ("Specified cast is not valid")?

Comment: I think you need to use serialization, not casting.  Serialization will put the data into an instance of MyClass.

Answer (score 1):

In the value return for Angular through a WEB API, C# has no way to now that the d variable was cast to MyClass.

Try Using:

```
MyClass myclass= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(item.d);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `as` keyword to downcast.

```
var mycls = item.d as MyClass;
if(mycls != null)
{
    //Do Something
}
```

If `mycls` is null then the type was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your property `d` as `MyClass` rather than `object` like

```
public MyClass d { get; set; }
```

In-case, you want that property to be of not `MyClass` and could be any supplied type then use generic probably

```
public class JsonRow<T>
    {
        public T d { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I think the OP is trying to make `d` a generic, but does not know how yet.

Comment: @maccettura, yes and me too think the same and so edited but yes that's guess too

Answer (score 0):

Try to Make it straight and easy for the compiler by declaring the d property as of type MyClass then d would be able to take assigned properties coming from the new MyClass without errors

```
public MyClass d { get; set; }
```